# CSS mapping with spring 3.2.4 MVC - no web.xml

Tags: css, eclipse, spring, model-view-controller, jetty

I have a spring MVC app I'm trying to run with eclipse and jetty. All annotations, no web.xml. After trying half the answers on here I still can't get my CSS to work.

My css is here

```
src/main/webapp/resources/css/main.css
```

And in my JSP I have

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value="/resources/css/main.css" />">
```

Which looks correct, resolves to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/resources/css/main.css">
```

I've tried adding this to me applicationContext.xml

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

And still it doesnt find the css.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

My initialiser

```
public class WebInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    private final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(WebInitializer.class);

    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {

        log.info("Starting web app");

        // Create the 'root' Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(AppConfig.class);
        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

        // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        dispatcherContext.register(MvcConfig.class);

        // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your browser's devtools say?

Comment: How is your `DispatcherServlet` mapped?

Comment: @M. Deinum, see my edit, added my initialiser.

Comment: Add `<mvc:default-servlet-handler />` to your configuration.

Comment: No luck. Still get a 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you can't combine XML and programmatic configuration.

I found [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-static-resources) link. After entering this in my config class it worked...

```
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/public-resources/");
  }

}
```